# Microsoft Translator API Python- Spanish locale languages returning same content

Tags: locale, microsoft-translator

As part of the Translate API, I am not seeing any differences between the different versions of Espanol translations - ie:  es-ES-Laura, es-ES-Pablo, es-MX-Raul and  es-MX-Sabina all return the same text translation as well as voice. Is this correct?

I was expecting differences between the "es" and "es-MX" versions.

Comment: I was requesting: features = "Partial,TimingInfo,TextToSpeech"

Answer (score 0):

The Translator API by default knows only one flavor of Spanish, which is based on content from all Spanish locales. You may create your own customized version using https://hub.microsofttranslator.com.